# what is the screen area returned by getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get the available screen area of my app programmatically.
To do so I am using `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize()` . However I am not quite sure of what is exactly the screen area corresponding to this 'Default Display Window'.

It seems to incorporate the whole screen (including the notification bar) except the navigation bar. Is this correct ? Are there exceptions ?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> Gets the size of the display, in pixels.
>
> Note that this value **should not be used for computing layouts**, since a
>   device will typically have screen decoration (such as a status bar)
>   along the edges of the display that reduce the amount of application
>   space available from the size returned here. Layouts should instead
>   use the window size.
>
> The size is adjusted based on the current rotation of the display.
>
> The size returned by this method **does not necessarily represent the
>   actual raw size** (native resolution) of the display. The returned size
>   **may be adjusted to exclude certain system decoration elements** that are
>   always visible. It may also be scaled to provide compatibility with
>   older applications that were originally designed for smaller displays.

Emphasis mine. So yes, it's possible they might exclude the navigation bar from it, but not necessarily.

Comment: Interesting answer. However, unless I am missing something, I can't get the space used by my Activity from the Window class. I wonder if there is a documentation error here..

Comment: I don't know of a way offhand to do that, no. I suppose it's sort of something you should try not to worry about, as it's able to change (say, if you go to fullscreen mode, or temporarily hiding the navigation bar). What exactly is your use case for needing to know the dimensions? You can always override your view's `onSizeChanged()` method and handle it there. If your view (or ViewGroup) is the root layout and is MATCH_PARENT for both dimensions, then the width and height you get would be the available activity space.

Comment: My use case is a drawing app. I need to provide a default drawing canvas size while leaving the possibility to choose custom dimensions. So I get the total space, remove the notification & action bar heights, as well as some margin and I get the vertical drawing space. Same thing horizontally with some margin & space for the tool. So far getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(), but its documentation make me fear that it could cause problems later on.

Comment: In fact, it is even a bit more complicated : I could simply use a layout that defines the margins to use. However, when I rotate the terminal, I can't simply let my layout recompute the size, since the total available space is not the same (due to the navigation & status bars). So I need to compute the size to use the first time in order to be able to keep it when I recreate the layout at screen rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it includes all space usable by your application (i.e., not counting OS level components like the status and notification bar).

However, the size does change based on whether use you methods such as `setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);` which hides the notification and status bar and gives your application temporarily more room.

Comment: Actually, if I compare the value given by this method to my screen space, it counts the notification bar, which is a bit strange.